# How to request all permission needed when the time user install the app in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app,but when user click "Install" button,the app install directly and it didn't prompt up to ask for permission for user to accept directly.So,I need to request permission during runtime.

But what I need to do,when user click "Install" button,request all the permission needed before the app start downloading from Google Play just like the image below:

[image]

So far my manifest is look like this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

So what I need to add in order to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think that this app is not request the permissions at runtime?

Comment: in app,I dont get any alert dialog that request permission during runtime.Is there anything I miss here??

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to have your `targetSdkVersion` below 23, which will force the request for permissions at install time.

Over time, seeing this permission dialog at install time will signal to prospective users that your app is obsolete and not being maintained. An increasing number of those prospective users will elect to not install your app as a result.

Also, bear in mind that users can still remove your requested permissions via the Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime permissions was introduced since 5.0 Android.
The reason that most of users don't read permissions while installation.
So, all up-to-date API have to use runtime permissions.
Even default apps such as Google maps require runtime permissions.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

If you don't want to use runtime permissions you have to use old API version. but you have to check. Your app may crash.

Comment: can I make sure the pop up dialog 100% show up in Google Play??cause when I install my app,it dont have the pop up dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For devices with android < 6.0 permissions are request at installation.
For devices with android > 6.0 permissions are request at runtime.

So if you want your app compatible with devices below and above 6.0, you need to declare permission in your Manifest.xml and request permission at runtime too.

[The official guide](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNm871vPnUAhVBPRQKHWt-AU8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fpermissions%2Frequesting.html&usg=AFQjCNGgVrDa_Fb9HkWDGSf0l_lYAj-XoA)